# Matching Strings and Count Frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of companies with their subsidiaries, the data looks as below:

```
CompanyName            Employees
Microsoft China          1
Microsoft India          1
Microsoft Europe         1
Apple Inc                1
Apple Data Inc           1
Apple Customer Service Inc   1
Data Corp                1
Data SHCH                1
Data India               1
City Corp                1
Data City                 1
```

If two companies have same words (e.g. Apple Inc and Apple Data Inc), they are considered one company. I will group those companies together, and calculate their total number of employees.

```
The expected return should be:
Company     Employees
Microsft     3
Apple        3
Data         3
City         2
```

1. The company will return the common word
2. The Employees return the sum of company and its subsidiaries

**Most of the pandas function doesn't really work in this case. Any suggestions on For Loop?**

Comment: You can have a look at a 'reduce' method, I think it can do this. Just need to make a quick search and I'll write an answer for you

Comment: There's a fast way, but it only works if the company name is always the first word, which doesn't seem to be the case for `Data City`. If the company is in mixed order in `CompanyName` then you'll need some list of unique company names.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Could you tell me the solution if the company name is always the first word? Thank you!

Comment: _Most of the pandas function doesn't really work in this case. Any suggestions on For Loop?_ Like I said, if the company can be anywhere in `CompanyName` then you will probably need a master list of unique company names. However, in the case of `Data City` when there is a company called `City` and a company called `Data`, I'm not certain how you would differentiate that.

Answer (score 1):

- As you requested in the comments

  - If the company is always the first word in `CompanyName`

```py
# extract company as word at index 0
df.CompanyName = df.CompanyName.str.split(expand=True)[0]

# groupby company name and count
dfg = df.groupby('CompanyName').agg({'CompanyName': 'count'})

# display(dfg)
             CompanyName
CompanyName             
Apple                  3
City                   1
Data                   4
Microsoft              3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a 'very' simple way to do what you want. But it's not too complex too.

First, you need to define clearly the ~criterion to decide wich names are the same 'company'.
We can try with "get the first world and see if it matches", obviously it's not a perfect approach, but it'll do for now.

Then, you can create an object to store your new data. I would recommend a dictionary, with entries like `company: (total employees)`.

You'll now iterate over the rows of the dataframe, with apply and a function to do what you want. It'll look like this:

```
dict = {}

def aggregator(row):
    word1 = row.company.split(" ")[0]
    
    if word1 in dict.keys:
       dict[word1] += row.employees

    else:
        dict[word1] = row.employees

dataframe.apply(aggregator, axis = 1)
```

Comment: I thought there was a method called reduce, that would pass the result of an iteration to the next one, that way you wouldn't have to define the dictionary manually. But I couldn't find it, maybe it has another name that I don't remember.

Comment: Sorry when I run this, I got this error. TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Comment: @KeFeng did you write DataFrame.apply or the name of your dataframe?